# how to toggle one div at the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

On my portfolio website, I have a full-width column of projects, where Ii wish that upon clicking the title the project display /.content slidetoggles downwards. Upon clicking any other project the former active project slides up and closes, whereas the new project displays. What is thee best way of targetting individual projects on click?

I have tried several things, from assigning a parent to the Title-Line-01, to straight-forward toggle jQuery, to assigning a different code to every single project I've read. through several articles here on Stack Overflow. But I still have not achieved the result I want. In the code below upon clicking any title - every projects displays.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".content").hide();
        $(".Title-line-01").click(function(){
            $(this).find('.content').toggle();
         });
    });
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
.mySlides1, .mySlides2, .mySlides3, .mySlides4, .mySlides5, .mySlides6, .mySlides7, .mySlides8, .mySlides9, .mySlides10,   
img {vertical-align: middle;}


@font-face {
  font-family: 'lirmaregular';
  src: url('lirma-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('lirma-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}


/* Information line in the top */

.Headline{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: wrap;
  font-family:'Helvetica Neue';
}

.Headline_1{
  flex:1;
  Align: center;
}

.Headline_2{
  flex:1;
  text-align: center;
}

.Headline_3{
  flex:1;
  text-align: center;
}

.Headline_4{
  flex:1;
  position: center;
  text-align: right;
}

/* Project and year */

.Title-line{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row
}

.Title-line-01{
  flex:1;
  font-family:'lirmaregular';
  font-size: 25px;
}

.Title-line-02{
  flex:1;
}

.Title-line-03{
  flex:1;
}

.Title-line-04{
  flex:1;
  font-family:'lirmaregular';
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 25px;
}

/* Specific projectnames */

.ProjectName-01{
  flex:1;
  font-family:'lirmaregular';
  font-size: 25px;
}

/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.content{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: wrap;
}

/* Specific contents */
.content-01{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: wrap;
}

.Flexbox_1{
  flex:1;
  font-family:'Helvetica Neue';
  font-size: 20px;
}

.Flexbox_2{
  flex:1;
}

.Flexbox_3{
  flex:1;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a grey background color */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="Headline">

    <div class="Headline_1">
          Carina Thornval 
    </div>  

    <div class="Headline_2">
          mail@cthornval.com 
    </div>  
    
    <div class="Headline_3">
      +4571580488
    </div>

    <div class="Headline_4">
      Curriculum vitae available upon request
    </div>

</div>



<div class="Project">

      <div class="Title-line">  
        
            <div class="Title-line-01">
                  <p>Region H</p>
            </class>

            <div class="Title-line-02">
                 
            </class>

            <div class="Title-line-03">
           
            </div>

            <div class="Title-line-04">
              <p>2021</p>
            </div>

      </div>  
        
      <div class="content">

                      <div class=Flexbox_1>
                            <p>
                              School Project <br>
                              Strategic design proposal 
                              <br> <br>

                              The Health and innovation unit of the Capital Region of 
                              <br> <br>
                              
                              <br> <br>

                              <a href="link"> Click here
                              </a>

                            </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
                      <div class=Flexbox_3>
                              <div class="slideshow-container">

                                
                                    <div class="mySlides1">
                                        <img src="Images/01_REG H/Instagram - landscape copy.mov" type="video/mp4" style="width:100%">
                                    </div>


                                    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
                                    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
                              </div>
                      </div>
            
</div>



<div class="Project">

                <div class="Title-line">  
                      
                        <div class="Title-line-01">
                              <p>CIFF</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="Title-line-02">
                            
                        </div>

                        <div class="Title-line-03">
                            
                        </div>

                        <div class="Title-line-04">
                            <p>2020</p>
                        </div>

                   </div>  
        
            <div class="content">

                    <div class=Flexbox_1>
                      <p>
                        School Project
                        <br>
                        Strategic design
                        <br> <br>
                        We were presented with the challenge of rethinking CIFF´s business model as the organisation was facing mounting challenges,
                        as they were prohibited from throwing their annual fashion fair at Bella Center, because of the outbreak of the coronavirus.
                        Therefor we proposed a new format for their trade fair: A digital platform, where brands and buyers can engage online through payingf a monthly subscription.
                        Moreover brands are invited to rent a physical "stage”/pavillion from where they can livestream content, 
                        through for example throwing events or having a showroom. The content produced will then reciprocally be distributed on the online platform.
                        The stage is a modular and mobile architectural entity, 
                        which can be placed all over the country and where the interior can be adapted to suit the needs of the brand renting the stage.
                        <br> <br>
                        This project was a collaboration with Fie Eleonora Mortensen, Gustavo Garcia og Laura Winter-Poulsen.
                        <br> <br>

                        <a href="">
                          Images and video
                        </a>
                      </p>

                    </div>
                    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
                    <div class=Flexbox_3>

                        <div class="slideshow-container">

                      

                              <div class="mySlides2">
                                <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_01 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                              </div>

                              <div class="mySlides2">
                                <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_02 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                              </div>

                              <div class="mySlides2">
                                <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_03 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                              </div>
                              
                              <div class="mySlides2">
                                <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_04 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                              </div>
                          
                              <div class="mySlides2">
                                <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_05 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                              </div>
                          
                              <div class="mySlides2">
                                <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_06 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                              </div>

                              <div class="mySlides2">
                                <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_07 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                              </div>

                              <div class="mySlides2">
                                <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_07 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                              </div>

                            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
                            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
</div>



<div class="Project">

      
          <div class="Title-line">  
                              
                  <div class="Title-line-01">
                        <p>Sofia Bordoni</p>
                  </div>

                  <div class="Title-line-02">
                      
                  </div>

                  <div class="Title-line-03">
                      
                  </div>

                  <div class="Title-line-04">
                      <p>2020</p>
                  </div>

           </div> 

          <div class="content">

                  <div class=Flexbox_1>
                    
                       <p>
                            Webpage design and development
                       </p>
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <a href="">
                      click here
                    </a>

                  </div>
                  <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
                  <div class=Flexbox_3>

                          <div class="slideshow-container">

                                  <div class="mySlides3">
                                    <img src="Images/03_Sofia Bordoni/SofiaBord.png" style="width:100%">
                                  </div>
                            

                            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 2)">&#10094;</a>
                            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 2)">&#10095;</a>
                          </div>
                  </div>
      </div>

</div>


<div class="Project">

            <div class="Title-line">  
                                        
                    <div class="Title-line-01">
                          <p>Lirma Type</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="Title-line-02">
                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="Title-line-03">
                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="Title-line-04">
                        <p>2020</p>
                    </div>

          </div> 

          <div class="content">

                  <div class=Flexbox_1>

                      <p>
                        Typedesign
                      </p>

                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <a href="">
                          Click here
                        </a>

                     
                  </div>
                  <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
                  <div class=Flexbox_3>

                          <div class="slideshow-container">

                                    <div class="mySlides4">
                                      <img src="Images/04_Lirma/type_new copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                    </div>

                            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 3)">&#10094;</a>
                            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 3)">&#10095;</a>
                        </div>
                  </div>
          </div>

</div>


<div class="Project">

            <div class="Title-line">  
                                      
                        <div class="Title-line-01">
                              <p>Wer Baut Der Stadt</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="Title-line-02">
                            
                        </div>

                        <div class="Title-line-03">
                            
                        </div>

                        <div class="Title-line-04">
                            <p>2018</p>
                        </div>

              </div> 

              <div class="content">

              <div class=Flexbox_1>

                    <p>
                      Identity and Font developed for the lecture series on architecture conducted by No Image in Berlin.
                    </p>

                  </div>
                  <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
                  <div class=Flexbox_3>
                   
                          <div class="slideshow-container">
                            
                                  <div class="mySlides5">
                                    <img src="Images/05_WER BAUT 2018/Wer_baut copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="mySlides5">
                                    <img src="Images/05_WER BAUT 2018/Poster_Wer_baut.png" style="width:100%">
                                  </div>

                            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 4)">&#10094;</a>
                            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 4)">&#10095;</a>
                  </div>
                  </div>
          </div>
</div>



<div class="Project">

          <div class="Title-line">  
                                              
                  <div class="Title-line-01">
                        <p>CAFX</p>
                  </div>

                  <div class="Title-line-02">
                      
                  </div>

                  <div class="Title-line-03">
                      
                  </div>

                  <div class="Title-line-04">
                      <p>2018</p>
                  </div>

        </div> 

            <div class="content">

                <div class=Flexbox_1>
                  <p>
                    Identity Design for Copenhagen Architecture Festival
                    <br>
                    2018
                  </p>


                </div>
                <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
                <div class=Flexbox_3>
                        <div class="slideshow-container">

                                  <div class="mySlides6">
                                    <img src="Images/06_CAFX/Wer_baut_red_poster.png" style="width:100%">
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="mySlides6">
                                    <img src="Images/06_CAFX/Wer_baut_green_poster.png" style="width:100%">
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="mySlides6">
                                    <img src="Images/06_CAFX/Wer_baut_blue_poster.png" style="width:100%">
                                  </div>
                                  
                                  <div class="mySlides6">
                                    <img src="Images/06_CAFX/IMG_0546 (1)_Cafx_7-kopi.png" style="width:100%">
                                  </div>
                              
                                  <div class="mySlides6">
                                    <img src="Images/06_CAFX/IMG_0546 (1)_Cafx_8-kopi.png" style="width:100%">
                                  </div>

                          <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 5)">&#10094;</a>
                          <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 5)">&#10095;</a>
                          
                        </div>
                </div>

              </div>
</div>

<div class="Project">

            <div class="Title-line">  
                                                        
                        <div class="Title-line-01">
                              <p>Contagious Tales</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="Title-line-02">
                            
                        </div>

                        <div class="Title-line-03">
                            
                        </div>

                        <div class="Title-line-04">
                            <p>2017</p>
                        </div>

          </div> 

                <div class="content">

                    <div class=Flexbox_1>

                      <p>
                        Graduation project, editorial design.
                      </p>

                    </div>
                    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
                    <div class=Flexbox_3>

                            <div class="slideshow-container">

                                        <div class="mySlides7">
                                          <img src="Images/07_Contagious Tales/Contagious_tales_01 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="mySlides7">
                                          <img src="Images/07_Contagious Tales/Contagious_tales_02 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="mySlides7">
                                          <img src="Images/07_Contagious Tales/Contagious_tales_3 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                        </div>


                              <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 6)">&#10094;</a>
                              <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 6)">&#10095;</a>

                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>


<div class="Project">
                
            <div class="Title-line">  
                                                                            
                        <div class="Title-line-01">
                              <p>FOAM X HYDRA</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="Title-line-02">
                            
                        </div>

                        <div class="Title-line-03">
                            
                        </div>

                        <div class="Title-line-04">
                            <p>2017</p>
                        </div>

            </div> 

                  <div class="content">

                      <div class=Flexbox_1>

                          <p>
                            Design of exhibition cahier in connection to the exhibition FOAM X HYDRA
                          <p>

                      </div>
                      <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
                      <div class=Flexbox_3>

                              <div class="slideshow-container">

                                          <div class="mySlides8">
                                            <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_01.png" style="width:100%">
                                          </div>

                                          <div class="mySlides8">
                                            <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_02.png" style="width:100%">
                                          </div>

                                          <div class="mySlides8">
                                            <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_3.png" style="width:100%">
                                          </div>
                                          
                                          <div class="mySlides8">
                                            <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_04.png" style="width:100%">
                                          </div>
                                      
                                          <div class="mySlides8">
                                            <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_05.png" style="width:100%">
                                          </div>

                                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 7)">&#10094;</a>
                                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 7)">&#10095;</a>
                              </div>
                    </div>

              </div>
</div>


<div class="Project">

        <div class="Title-line">  
                                                                                  
                  <div class="Title-line-01">
                        <p>Money Publication</p>
                  </div>

                  <div class="Title-line-02">
                      
                  </div>

                  <div class="Title-line-03">
                      
                  </div>

                  <div class="Title-line-04">
                      <p>2017</p>
                  </div>

      </div> 

        <div class="content">

              <div class=Flexbox_1>

                    <p>
                        Publication design with text by Christopher Deutschmann and Paul Larfague
                    </p>
              </div>
              <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
              <div class=Flexbox_3>

                      <div class="slideshow-container">

                                    <div class="mySlides9">
                                      <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_6 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="mySlides9">
                                      <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_1 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="mySlides9">
                                      <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_3 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="mySlides9">
                                      <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_4 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                    </div>
                                
                                    <div class="mySlides9">
                                      <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_5 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                    </div>


                        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 8)">&#10094;</a>
                        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 8)">&#10095;</a>

                      </div>
              </div>
        </div>
</div>


<div class="Project">

            <div class="Title-line">  
                                                                                                    
                      <div class="Title-line-01">
                            <p>What is the newsarticle?</p>
                      </div>

                      <div class="Title-line-02">
                          
                      </div>

                      <div class="Title-line-03">
                          
                      </div>

                      <div class="Title-line-04">
                          <p>2017</p>
                      </div>

          </div> 

            <div class="content">

                      <div class=Flexbox_1>
                        <p>
                          Publication design with text by Christopher Deutschmann and Paul Larfague
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
                      <div class=Flexbox_3>

                              <div class="slideshow-container">

                                            <div class="mySlides10">
                                              <img src="Images/10_Newsarticle/Newsletter_1 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="mySlides10">
                                              <img src="Images/10_Newsarticle/newsletter_2 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="mySlides10">
                                              <img src="Images/10_Newsarticle/newsletter_3 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                            </div>


                                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 9)">&#10094;</a>
                                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 9)">&#10095;</a>

                              </div>
                      </div>
            </div>
</div>



<script src="Slideshows.js"></script>
<script src="Toggle.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've done this before but it is very cumbersome. I'd recommend trying the bootstrap accordion. It does all of the hard work for you: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/#how-it-works

Comment: For starters, your HTML is invalid. There's no `</class>` tag which you have several of

Answer (score -1):

Would it be a bad idea to set id's for your elements?

Set id's for the class "content" divs, and set onclick event for the class "Project" divs.

Class "content" display is initially set to "none".

Of course, add a little code for the onclick event.

In time: in your code there's a few divs closed with `</class>`. I fixed that.

```js
/* This code closes the project when you click on it,
 cause it tracks the outter div (class "Project")

var iShown = 0;

function Show_Content(iContent) {        
    if (iShown > 0) {
        document.getElementById("content" + iShown).style.display = "none";
    }
    
    if (iContent !== iShown) {
        document.getElementById("content" + iContent).style.display = "block";
        iShown = iContent;
    } else {
        iShown = 0;
    }
}
*/


/*This code only closes a project when you open a different one*/
var iShown = 0;

function Show_Content(iContent) {
    if (iShown == 0) {
        document.getElementById("content" + iContent).style.display = "block";
    } else if (iContent !== iShown) {
        document.getElementById("content" + iShown).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("content" + iContent).style.display = "block";
    }
    iShown = iContent;
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
.mySlides1, .mySlides2, .mySlides3, .mySlides4, .mySlides5, .mySlides6, .mySlides7, .mySlides8, .mySlides9, .mySlides10,   
img {vertical-align: middle;}


@font-face {
  font-family: 'lirmaregular';
  src: url('lirma-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('lirma-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}


/* Information line in the top */

.Headline{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: wrap;
  font-family:'Helvetica Neue';
}

.Headline_1{
  flex:1;
  Align: center;
}

.Headline_2{
  flex:1;
  text-align: center;
}

.Headline_3{
  flex:1;
  text-align: center;
}

.Headline_4{
  flex:1;
  position: center;
  text-align: right;
}

/* Project and year */

.Title-line{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row
}

.Title-line-01{
  flex:1;
  font-family:'lirmaregular';
  font-size: 25px;
}

.Title-line-02{
  flex:1;
}

.Title-line-03{
  flex:1;
}

.Title-line-04{
  flex:1;
  font-family:'lirmaregular';
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 25px;
}

/* Specific projectnames */

.ProjectName-01{
  flex:1;
  font-family:'lirmaregular';
  font-size: 25px;
}

/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.content{
  display: none;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: wrap;
}

/* Specific contents */
.content-01{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: wrap;
}

.Flexbox_1{
  flex:1;
  font-family:'Helvetica Neue';
  font-size: 20px;
}

.Flexbox_2{
  flex:1;
}

.Flexbox_3{
  flex:1;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a grey background color */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="Headline">

<div class="Headline_1">
      Carina Thornval 
</div>  

<div class="Headline_2">
      mail@cthornval.com 
</div>  

<div class="Headline_3">
  +4571580488
</div>

<div class="Headline_4">
  Curriculum vitae available upon request
</div>

</div>



<div onclick="Show_Content(1)" class="Project">

  <div class="Title-line">  
    
        <div class="Title-line-01">
              <p>Region H</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Title-line-02">
             
        </div>

        <div class="Title-line-03">
       
        </div>

        <div class="Title-line-04">
          <p>2021</p>
        </div>

  </div>  
              <div id="content1" class="content">

                  <div class=Flexbox_1>
                        <p>
                          School Project <br>
                          Strategic design proposal 
                          <br> <br>

                          The Health and innovation unit of the Capital Region of 
                          <br> <br>
                          
                          <br> <br>

                          <a href="link"> Click here
                          </a>

                        </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
                  <div class=Flexbox_3>
                          <div class="slideshow-container">

                            
                                <div class="mySlides1">
                                    <img src="Images/01_REG H/Instagram - landscape copy.mov" type="video/mp4" style="width:100%">
                                </div>


                                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
                                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
                          </div>
                  </div>
        
</div>

</div>

<div onclick="Show_Content(2)" class="Project">

            <div class="Title-line">  
                  
                    <div class="Title-line-01">
                          <p>CIFF</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="Title-line-02">
                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="Title-line-03">
                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="Title-line-04">
                        <p>2020</p>
                    </div>

               </div>  
    
        <div id="content2" class="content">

                <div class=Flexbox_1>
                  <p>
                    School Project
                    <br>
                    Strategic design
                    <br> <br>
                    We were presented with the challenge of rethinking CIFF´s business model as the organisation was facing mounting challenges,
                    as they were prohibited from throwing their annual fashion fair at Bella Center, because of the outbreak of the coronavirus.
                    Therefor we proposed a new format for their trade fair: A digital platform, where brands and buyers can engage online through payingf a monthly subscription.
                    Moreover brands are invited to rent a physical "stage”/pavillion from where they can livestream content, 
                    through for example throwing events or having a showroom. The content produced will then reciprocally be distributed on the online platform.
                    The stage is a modular and mobile architectural entity, 
                    which can be placed all over the country and where the interior can be adapted to suit the needs of the brand renting the stage.
                    <br> <br>
                    This project was a collaboration with Fie Eleonora Mortensen, Gustavo Garcia og Laura Winter-Poulsen.
                    <br> <br>

                    <a href="">
                      Images and video
                    </a>
                  </p>

                </div>
                <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
                <div class=Flexbox_3>

                    <div class="slideshow-container">

                  

                          <div class="mySlides2">
                            <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_01 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                          </div>

                          <div class="mySlides2">
                            <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_02 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                          </div>

                          <div class="mySlides2">
                            <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_03 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                          </div>
                          
                          <div class="mySlides2">
                            <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_04 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                          </div>
                      
                          <div class="mySlides2">
                            <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_05 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                          </div>
                      
                          <div class="mySlides2">
                            <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_06 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                          </div>

                          <div class="mySlides2">
                            <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_07 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                          </div>

                          <div class="mySlides2">
                            <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_07 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                          </div>

                        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
                        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>


<div onclick="Show_Content(3)" class="Project">

  
      <div class="Title-line">  
                          
              <div class="Title-line-01">
                    <p>Sofia Bordoni</p>
              </div>

              <div class="Title-line-02">
                  
              </div>

              <div class="Title-line-03">
                  
              </div>

              <div class="Title-line-04">
                  <p>2020</p>
              </div>

       </div> 

        <div id="content3" class="content">

              <div class=Flexbox_1>
                
                   <p>
                        Webpage design and development
                   </p>
                <br>
                <br>

                <a href="">
                  click here
                </a>

              </div>
              <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
              <div class=Flexbox_3>

                      <div class="slideshow-container">

                              <div class="mySlides3">
                                <img src="Images/03_Sofia Bordoni/SofiaBord.png" style="width:100%">
                              </div>
                        

                        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 2)">&#10094;</a>
                        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 2)">&#10095;</a>
                      </div>
              </div>
  </div>

</div>


<div onclick="Show_Content(4)" class="Project">

        <div class="Title-line">  
                                    
                <div class="Title-line-01">
                      <p>Lirma Type</p>
                </div>

                <div class="Title-line-02">
                    
                </div>

                <div class="Title-line-03">
                    
                </div>

                <div class="Title-line-04">
                    <p>2020</p>
                </div>

      </div> 

        <div id="content4" class="content">

              <div class=Flexbox_1>

                  <p>
                    Typedesign
                  </p>

                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <a href="">
                      Click here
                    </a>

                 
              </div>
              <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
              <div class=Flexbox_3>

                      <div class="slideshow-container">

                                <div class="mySlides4">
                                  <img src="Images/04_Lirma/type_new copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                </div>

                        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 3)">&#10094;</a>
                        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 3)">&#10095;</a>
                    </div>
              </div>
      </div>

</div>


<div onclick="Show_Content(5)" class="Project">

        <div class="Title-line">  
                                  
                    <div class="Title-line-01">
                          <p>Wer Baut Der Stadt</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="Title-line-02">
                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="Title-line-03">
                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="Title-line-04">
                        <p>2018</p>
                    </div>

          </div> 

            <div id="content5" class="content">

          <div class=Flexbox_1>

                <p>
                  Identity and Font developed for the lecture series on architecture conducted by No Image in Berlin.
                </p>

              </div>
              <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
              <div class=Flexbox_3>
               
                      <div class="slideshow-container">
                        
                              <div class="mySlides5">
                                <img src="Images/05_WER BAUT 2018/Wer_baut copy.png" style="width:100%">
                              </div>

                              <div class="mySlides5">
                                <img src="Images/05_WER BAUT 2018/Poster_Wer_baut.png" style="width:100%">
                              </div>

                        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 4)">&#10094;</a>
                        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 4)">&#10095;</a>
              </div>
              </div>
      </div>
</div>



<div onclick="Show_Content(6)" class="Project">

      <div class="Title-line">  
                                          
              <div class="Title-line-01">
                    <p>CAFX</p>
              </div>

              <div class="Title-line-02">
                  
              </div>

              <div class="Title-line-03">
                  
              </div>

              <div class="Title-line-04">
                  <p>2018</p>
              </div>

    </div> 

          <div id="content6" class="content">

            <div class=Flexbox_1>
              <p>
                Identity Design for Copenhagen Architecture Festival
                <br>
                2018
              </p>


            </div>
            <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
            <div class=Flexbox_3>
                    <div class="slideshow-container">

                              <div class="mySlides6">
                                <img src="Images/06_CAFX/Wer_baut_red_poster.png" style="width:100%">
                              </div>

                              <div class="mySlides6">
                                <img src="Images/06_CAFX/Wer_baut_green_poster.png" style="width:100%">
                              </div>

                              <div class="mySlides6">
                                <img src="Images/06_CAFX/Wer_baut_blue_poster.png" style="width:100%">
                              </div>
                              
                              <div class="mySlides6">
                                <img src="Images/06_CAFX/IMG_0546 (1)_Cafx_7-kopi.png" style="width:100%">
                              </div>
                          
                              <div class="mySlides6">
                                <img src="Images/06_CAFX/IMG_0546 (1)_Cafx_8-kopi.png" style="width:100%">
                              </div>

                      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 5)">&#10094;</a>
                      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 5)">&#10095;</a>
                      
                    </div>
            </div>

          </div>
</div>

<div onclick="Show_Content(7)" class="Project">

        <div class="Title-line">  
                                                    
                    <div class="Title-line-01">
                          <p>Contagious Tales</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="Title-line-02">
                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="Title-line-03">
                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="Title-line-04">
                        <p>2017</p>
                    </div>

      </div> 

              <div id="content7" class="content">

                <div class=Flexbox_1>

                  <p>
                    Graduation project, editorial design.
                  </p>

                </div>
                <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
                <div class=Flexbox_3>

                        <div class="slideshow-container">

                                    <div class="mySlides7">
                                      <img src="Images/07_Contagious Tales/Contagious_tales_01 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="mySlides7">
                                      <img src="Images/07_Contagious Tales/Contagious_tales_02 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="mySlides7">
                                      <img src="Images/07_Contagious Tales/Contagious_tales_3 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                    </div>


                          <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 6)">&#10094;</a>
                          <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 6)">&#10095;</a>

                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>


<div onclick="Show_Content(8)" class="Project">
            
        <div class="Title-line">  
                                                                        
                    <div class="Title-line-01">
                          <p>FOAM X HYDRA</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="Title-line-02">
                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="Title-line-03">
                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="Title-line-04">
                        <p>2017</p>
                    </div>

        </div> 

                <div id="content8" class="content">

                  <div class=Flexbox_1>

                      <p>
                        Design of exhibition cahier in connection to the exhibition FOAM X HYDRA
                      <p>

                  </div>
                  <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
                  <div class=Flexbox_3>

                          <div class="slideshow-container">

                                      <div class="mySlides8">
                                        <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_01.png" style="width:100%">
                                      </div>

                                      <div class="mySlides8">
                                        <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_02.png" style="width:100%">
                                      </div>

                                      <div class="mySlides8">
                                        <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_3.png" style="width:100%">
                                      </div>
                                      
                                      <div class="mySlides8">
                                        <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_04.png" style="width:100%">
                                      </div>
                                  
                                      <div class="mySlides8">
                                        <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_05.png" style="width:100%">
                                      </div>

                            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 7)">&#10094;</a>
                            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 7)">&#10095;</a>
                          </div>
                </div>

          </div>
</div>


<div onclick="Show_Content(9)" class="Project">

    <div class="Title-line">  
                                                                              
              <div class="Title-line-01">
                    <p>Money Publication</p>
              </div>

              <div class="Title-line-02">
                  
              </div>

              <div class="Title-line-03">
                  
              </div>

              <div class="Title-line-04">
                  <p>2017</p>
              </div>

  </div> 

        <div id="content9" class="content">

          <div class=Flexbox_1>

                <p>
                    Publication design with text by Christopher Deutschmann and Paul Larfague
                </p>
          </div>
          <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
          <div class=Flexbox_3>

                  <div class="slideshow-container">

                                <div class="mySlides9">
                                  <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_6 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                </div>

                                <div class="mySlides9">
                                  <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_1 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                </div>

                                <div class="mySlides9">
                                  <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_3 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="mySlides9">
                                  <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_4 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                </div>
                            
                                <div class="mySlides9">
                                  <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_5 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                </div>


                    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 8)">&#10094;</a>
                    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 8)">&#10095;</a>

                  </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div onclick="Show_Content(10)" class="Project">

        <div class="Title-line">  
                                                                                                
                  <div class="Title-line-01">
                        <p>What is the newsarticle?</p>
                  </div>

                  <div class="Title-line-02">
                      
                  </div>

                  <div class="Title-line-03">
                      
                  </div>

                  <div class="Title-line-04">
                      <p>2017</p>
                  </div>

      </div> 

          <div id="content10" class="content">

                  <div class=Flexbox_1>
                    <p>
                      Publication design with text by Christopher Deutschmann and Paul Larfague
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
                  <div class=Flexbox_3>

                          <div class="slideshow-container">

                                        <div class="mySlides10">
                                          <img src="Images/10_Newsarticle/Newsletter_1 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="mySlides10">
                                          <img src="Images/10_Newsarticle/newsletter_2 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="mySlides10">
                                          <img src="Images/10_Newsarticle/newsletter_3 copy.png" style="width:100%">
                                        </div>


                            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 9)">&#10094;</a>
                            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 9)">&#10095;</a>

                          </div>
                  </div>
        </div>
</div>
 
<script src="Slideshows.js"></script>
<script src="Toggle.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn´t downvote your code. I tried to implement it and it works great, apart from the fact that when Ii click on the slideshows-container the div closes.  Is there anyway of assigning every title with its .content div so, so it stays open while you go thrugh the project?

Comment: also Stackoverflow does nott allow me tto upvote your code again.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood you. You want to keep the project open, so it will close only when you open a different one? I'll put the code up there.

Comment: It would be wonderful, if you could do so :)

Comment: And yes, that is precisely, what II would like